# How do you push ng-repeat value to controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, submit

I want to populate a webpage using ng-repeat and the following array:

```
var array = [{name: Bill, age: 12, number: 1}, {name: Tyrone, age: 11, number: 2}, {name: Sarah, age: 14, number: 3}];
```

I want to be able to push a button and return to my Angular controller the name or number value for the given person.  I don't know how to do this though I've tried with both button and input attempts with no success. You can see one of the attempts in the example code below.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1" class="text-center">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th colspan="1" class="text-center">
                    Age
                </th>
                <th colspan="1" class="text-center">
                    Number
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody filter-list="search"ng-repeat="a in array">
            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-6">
                    {{a.name}}
                </td>
                <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                    <button ng-click="Age()" ng-model="a.age">This Age</button>
                </td>
                <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xl-2">
                    <input type="button" name="number" ng-click="Number()" ng-model="a.number" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller is as follows:

```
angular.module('startupApp')
  .controller('ManageCardCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http) {

var array = [{name: Bill, age: 12, number: 1}, {name: Tyrone, age: 11, number: 2}, {name: Sarah, age: 14, number: 3}];

$scope.Age = function(){
      $http.post('api/age', {age: $scope.age})
          .success(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
          })
          .error(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
    }


    $scope.number = function(){
        $http.post('api/number', {number: $scope.number})
            .success(function (response) {
              console.log(response)
            })
            .error(function (error) {
              console.log(error)
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the data you want to use in the function's parameters:

```
<button ng-click="Age(a.age)">This Age</button>
```

---

```
$scope.Age = function(age) {
  $http.post('api/age', {age: age})
      .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .error(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a mil! I've done this before though I did not pick up on it because of different use cases. Finally able to move on!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each person as `Age` argument:

```
<td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
   <button ng-click="Age(a)" ng-model="a.age">This Age</button>
</td>
```

And you'll get the concrete bound person as argument in your `Age` function:

```
$scope.Age = function(a) {
   var age = a.age;
};
```

I suggest this as a better approach than giving `a.Age` directly, because Angular implements data-binding paradigm and I feel that you want *the bound object* rather than *the property of who knows what object*. In other words, this gives the flexibility to work with more than a bound object property in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

First, var array, is not accessible in the page scope.  You will need to change it too:

```
$scope.array = ({name: 'Bill', age: 12, number: 1}, ...)
```

notice also in the above that name: should be a string.  So add single quotes around the names. 'Bill', 'Tyrone'

Then, you just need to pass a parameter into the function:

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="Age(a.age)" ng-model="a.age">This Age</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.Age = function(age) {
  $http.post('api/age', {age: age})
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps.  The To-do app on the angulars homepage is a great reference for this. [Angular To-Do List](https://angularjs.org/#add-some-control)